# Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:

Tags: android, permissions, location

I am getting this exception in the crash reporting but I cant reproduce the crash by myself. It seems that everything works fine but somehow it happens on a few users. Does someone had a similar problem like this one?

```
    Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
    ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=22, result=0, 
    data=null} to activity {}: java.lang.SecurityException: "network" 
    location 
    provider requires ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION 
    permission.
```

Comment: Either you never requested runtime permissions, or the user revoked them and you did not request those permissions again.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am requesting permissions at run time

Comment: Then the user revoked them, and you did not re-request those permissions. Perhaps your permission checks are in the wrong location.

Answer (score 1):

In onResume check if there is any permission denied, if so ask for permissions. onCreate is risky because this method is called once when Activity is created.

Maybe this is your use case:

user add permissions, tap home button -> remove permissions for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Check your target Sdk version. If it's 23 or above then lower it to 22 or below as 23 or above Sdk versions require run time permissions and would crash your app if you have mentioned those permissions in just the manifest file. Some permissions are however allowed to just be mentioned in the manifest file.

Go to this link for more details:
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Also put your permissions outside the application tag in manifest file and then check whether the app still crashes or not.